# Which shell does Perl 6's shell() use?

Tags: shell, raku

Perl 6's [shell](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/shell) sends commands to the "shell" but doesn't say what that is. I consistently get *bash* on my machine but I don't know if I can rely on that.

```
$ perl6 -e 'shell( Q/echo $SHELL/ )'
/bin/bash
$ csh
% perl6 -e 'shell( Q/echo $SHELL/ )'
/bin/bash
% zsh
$ perl6 -e 'shell( Q/echo $SHELL/ )'
/bin/bash
```

That's easy enough on Unix when it's documented, but what about *cmd.exe* or PowerShell on Windows (or bash if it's installed)? I figure it's the *cmd.exe* but a documented answer would be nice.

Comment: Filed as an [issue in `perl6/doc`](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1964). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/2018.04/src/core/Proc.pm6#L166), rakudo just calls `/bin/sh -c` on non-windows and uses `%*ENV<ComSpec> /c` on windows.

Comment: Then on Ubuntu it should be dash: `/bin/sh -> dash`. But it's bash.

Comment: on ubuntu it is indeed dash. what did you do to check what shell you were getting?

Comment: `perl6 -e 'shell( Q/echo $SHELL/ )'` gives `/bin/bash`

Comment: @EugeneBarsky `dash -c 'echo $SHELL'` also gives `/bin/bash` on my computer.

Comment: both `perl6 -e 'shell( Q/echo $SHELL/ )'` and `dash -c 'echo $SHELL'` give me an empty line, but I used `perl6 -e 'shell "sleep 100"'` and checked the process id via `ps faux` and then `ls -ls /proc/the-pid/exe` which gave me `/proc/7162/exe -> /bin/dash`

Comment: @timotimo Thanks, I'll keep in mind it's dash, never thought about that.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky : You are printing the content of the variable `SHELL`. This is not necessarily the shell you are running right now. Try it with the command `SHELL=blabla dash -c 'echo $SHELL'`. Even if you know now that you are running dash, the output is *blabla* and not */bin/dash*.

Comment: @user1934428 Of course. Then what's the best way to know the current shell?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky : You have no real guarantee anyway, what shell you get. The shell may be /bin/sh, which in turn might be symlinked to dash, bash or whatever. At least in Perl 5, you could find the out what Perl is calling, by accessing the [config module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html#s), but I don't know how this is done in Perl 6. In any case, if your code relies on a certain shell, it is better to provide the shell explicitly.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, now I at least understand it.

Comment: fwiw I get /bin/zsh on MacOS from perl6 -e 'shell( Q/echo $SHELL/ )'

Answer (score 2):

`dash` (installed as `/bin/sh` on many systems), doesn't set `$SHELL`, nor should it. `$SHELL` isn't the name of the parent process; it's the name of the shell that should be used when an interactive shell is desired.

To get the name of the parent process, you could use the following on some systems:

```
echo "$0"
```

or

```
# Command line
perl -e'$ppid=getppid(); @ARGV="/proc/$ppid/cmdline"; CORE::say "".<>'
```

or

```
# Program file
perl -e'$ppid=getppid(); CORE::say readlink("/proc/$ppid/exe")'
```

You'll find you'll get `/bin/sh` in all cases.