# How to run shell command in Perl, like Raku?

Tags: perl, raku

I have excellent code in Raku:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
CONTROL {
    when CX::Warn {
        note $_;
        die
    }
}
use fatal;
role KeyRequired {
    method AT-KEY (\key) {
        die "Key {key} not found" unless self.EXISTS-KEY(key);
        nextsame
    }
}

sub execute ($cmd) {
    put $cmd;
    my $proc = shell $cmd, :err, :out;
    if $proc.exitcode != 0 {
        put 'exit code = ' ~ $proc.exitcode;
        put 'stderr ' ~ $proc.err.slurp;
       put 'stdout ' ~ $proc.out.slurp;
        die
    }
}

execute "ls *.p6"
```

I say "excellent" because the Raku version runs a command, returns an exit code, and prints stdout/stderr if needed, and all in an easily-read and easily-understood manner.

Reading through the Perl5 manual for `IPC::Run` https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run I've come across what appears to be the best Perl5 way of doing this, but I find the methods used there to be much less easily readable and understood than the Raku way of doing things.

Reading through the manual for `IPC::Run` the best that I can find is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie qw(:all);
use IPC::Run qw(run timeout);

sub execute {
    my $cmd = shift;

    my @cat = ('cat', __FILE__); # Raku doesn't need to split the string into an array
    run \@cat, \undef, \my $out, \my $err, timeout( 10 ) or die "cat: $?"; 
    if ($out ne '') {
        say "\$out = $out";
    }
    if ($err ne '') {
        say "\$err = $err";
    }
}

execute("cat " . __FILE__);

execute("cat __Fle");  #intentionally wrong to produce an error
```

How can I re-write the Perl5 so that it is as easily read and used as the Raku code?

Comment: Are you looking for the `run $cmd, ...` variant where `$cmd` is a string? The docs are not very explicit about this mode, but it's used in some examples. If you want access to the exit code you should manually `start()` a harness though.

Comment: @amon where `$cmd` is a string is just one change that I'd like, the whole harness thing looks really complicated, so I guess that I'm trying to avoid having a harness.  Raku does this so much better than IPC::Run

Comment: So then is this whole Q a statement how "_Raku does this so much better_" ...?  Otherwise I am not sure what more you want in Perl5 ... what does it mean "_easily read_"?  What is not easily read in Perl5 code you show?  Btw, the main thing about `IPC::Run` is that you can do _a lot_ with it -- perhaps you'll find code from other related modules "easier"?

Comment: Can shave off one line if that's going to help, by `run [ 'cat', __FILE__ ], ...` (so create an anonymous arrayref (`[ ... ]`) instead of creating an array and taking its reference)

Comment: @zdim "So then is this whole Q a statement how "Raku does this so much better" ...?" Afaik .@con has been happily getting stuff done for several years using Perl; has been using Raku too in the last couple; and is steadily expanding his programming skills but prefers to know how to do any given task in both languages rather than just one. I looked into this Q because I was uncomfortable with the the way .@con described things, but having researched it I think I have a better idea of why. See [my notes](https://gist.github.com/raiph/807a02248385cea6b0bc809d4f56a837) for what I'm talking about.

Comment: @raiph So that Raku code runs a shell?  Then the shown invocation of `IPC::Run` isn't the right equivalent because it _doesn't run_ (no stinkin') shell. (For me it is rare that I need a shell; I want to run a program.)

Comment: @raiph I get the argument but ... simplify one straight line of code? Really?

Comment: Re "*Raku doesn't need to split the string into an array*", Neither does `run`. You can use `run $shell_command`. This is something you normally want to *avoid*, so `run` is better in that it doesn't force you to use a shell command.

Comment: @zadim "runs a shell?" Yes. As `shell`'s doc says "Shell escapes are a severe security concern and can cause confusion with unusual file names. Use [`run`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/run#(Independent_routines)_sub_run) if you want to be safe." That doc in turn says, "Runs an external command *without involving a shell* and returns a `Proc` object." So, same API, but safer. "simplify one straight line of code? Really?" I see there are answers but have not read them. Right now I don't know what that one line is. Having researched (see my notes above) I suspect that's .@con's problem.

Comment: @raiph "_don't know what that one line is_ -- well, what's indicated in my comment above. It's one line, and then you go print out/err etc -- just like their Raku example. I don't care whether there is one little bit that you can or cannot do the same way, this is the same code "complexity" (triviality rather).

Comment: @raiph    Note that their example is skewed -- they don't check whether there is out/err like they do for Perl.  Reminds me of some other languages whereby the inspired adherents "compare" an artificially convoluted (and bad) Perl code with a simplified, incomplete version in "their" language.  Not cool to see that pattern within Perl itself.

Comment: @raiph Given the extended (unintended) exchange, just to clarify myself -- I don't object to a statement that Raku (code) is "nicer" or better" or what have you.  (I hope that it is!)

Answer (score 3):

You've unfairly loaded the Perl 5 example with a lot of extra fluff, and you haven't handled many things in the Raku code. For instance, you output the results in Raku despite what's in the variables, but test the variables in Perl 5.

Your Perl 5 would look more like this:

```
use v5.30;
use IPC::Run qw(run timeout);

sub execute {
    my @command = @_;
    run \@command, \undef, \my $out, \my $err, timeout( 10 ) 
        or die "cat: $?"; 
    say "\$out = $out";
    say "\$err = $err";
}

execute("cat ", __FILE__);
```

ikegami offered this version in his pastebin link:

```
sub execute {
    my ($command) = @_;
    if (! run $command, \undef, \my $out, \my $err, timeout( 10 ) ) {
       say "exit code = $?";
       say "stderr $err";
       put "stdout $out";
       die "Died";
   }
}
```

There's an interesting thing to note in both of those cases. You are assuming an error if the exit code is not zero (and Raku assumes that, which is why you have to worry about not sinking the result). However, many useful programs don't follow that convention. For instance, `git merge base` uses exit value 1 to mean "not an ancestor" and all exit values higher than 1 to mean an error. The command-line `grep` is similar. sendmail had exit code 75 to mean that something didn't work out, but it would try again later.

Raku, having an opinion on that, ignores this sort of thing and does not allow you to tell the Proc which exit values it should accept as successful exits. Perl 5 is not so opinionated. Using `or die` or `! ...` is really saying "exit code is not zero", but that's not really a good enough description. In many cases you get away with it, but at least Perl 5 isn't deciding for you. If you expanded the Raku example to check the literal value and decide if that's successful, it will look messy.

---

But, notice that Raku's `shell` documentation notes that it's unsafe and that you should use `run` instead.

For what it's worth, I don't find Raku's interprocess communication all that trustworthy. In many cases, I think its IPC design was neglected. See, for instance, [Does changing Perl 6's $*OUT change standard output for child processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505139/does-changing-perl-6s-out-change-standard-output-for-child-processes) . I have several other IPC questions spread out in bug reports and in Stackoverflow, and almost none of them received a satisfactory answer. Mostly, I think that's because nobody thought about it that much. Granted, Raku is developed by a small team and its a big project, but when it comes to production programming, that's no factor.

Some more Raku shell weirdness:

- [Which shell does Perl 6's shell() use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50029941/which-shell-does-perl-6s-shell-use)

Comment: The link you added (Which shell does Perl 6's shell() use) doesn't illustrate "Raku shell weirdness"; it was simply a bad test on the part of the OP.

Comment: Well, it's not hard to have a bad test when the docs aren't clear.

Comment: Iirc Raku's `run` was named to be consistent with Perl convention, perhaps due to `IPC::Run`, and the Perl `run` doesn't use the shell either. If I'm right about the latter, what would be the Perl equivalent of Raku's `shell`? If I'm wrong, what would be the Perl equivalent of Raku's `run`?

Comment: There are lots of things about Raku that tried to be consistent with Perl but ending not not being consistent.